# How could I implement a centered shear an image with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, affinetransform

When I use warpAffine to shear an image:

```
M2 = np.float32([[1, 0, 0], [0.2, 1, 0]])
aff2 = cv2.warpAffine(im, M2, (W, H))
```

I obtain an image that is not sheared around the image center. I can see black triangular areas on one side of the image, and the other side does not have black areas.

How could I let the image be sheared symmetricly ?

Comment: You need to expand the output image larger than the input image, when doing shear. So make your W or H larger by the amount of shear in in pixels

Comment: Would you be more specific? How could I know the amount of shear and its relationship with the number of pixels?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Have done any Google or Stackoverflow searches? I just did a Google search "Python opencv shear image" and found this. I suspect it will answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425701/shear-an-image-without-cropping

Comment: CONTINUED: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix. Note the shear matrix. Get k*width or k*height for the additional space. How did you compute your affine matrix, M2?

Comment: See also examples at https://imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/affine/#affine_shear and equations at https://imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#affine_projection for the matrix. Also I have a bash shell script for ImageMagick that does shear in pixels or degrees called skew at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/skew/index.php. ImageMagick automatically expands the image, so that you do not need to mess with that yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to adjust your translation parameters (3rd column) to center your image. i.e. you have to translate half the width and height multiplied by a factor.

For example

```
M2 = np.float32([[1, 0, 0], [0.2, 1, 0]])
M2[0,2] = -M2[0,1] * W/2
M2[1,2] = -M2[1,0] * H/2
aff2 = cv2.warpAffine(im, M2, (W, H))
```

#### Before

[image]

#### After

[image]

#### Full code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = np.ones((100,100))
H, W = im.shape

M2 = np.float32([[1, 0, 0], [0.2, 1, 0]])
M2[0,2] = -M2[0,1] * W/2
M2[1,2] = -M2[1,0] * H/2
aff2 = cv2.warpAffine(im, M2, (W, H))

plt.imshow(aff2, cmap="gray")
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the details in OpenCV and example. It always helps to get visuals.

Comment: Unfortunately, OP did not learn from [his previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57863376). The answer to this question is the same.

Comment: I found that in this script it should be 
`M2[0,2] = -M2[0,1] * H/2` and 
`M2[1,2] = -M2[1,0] * W/2`
I mean that W and H are messed.